# Using "Too" to disagree with negative sentence

Tags: conjunctions

In a sentence I want to disagree with the speaker:

- I can't speak english
- I can, too.

Is right to use "I can, too" in this case?

Ps.: I found this example on [5minuteenglish](http://www.5minuteenglish.com/mar4.htm) (B and C say the same thing in a different way according to the website)

[image]

Comment: You should check out [ell.se].

Comment: No - you can't use *I can too* to confirm that you also ***can't*** do something. Although it's a bit "stilted", you could (just about) say *I too can't*, but note that it's not at all idiomatic to say *I can't too* (in a "negating" context, that would have to be *I can't **either**).* Finally, note that the exchange *"You can't speak English!" - "I can too!"* is valid (if "slangy"), where ***too*** imparts *emphasis* to the refutation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers B and C say the same thing in a different way. Ex.: I can = I can, too. I just want to know if using "too" after comma when you disagree with negative sentence is right.

Comment: These might be OK if said by the right person in the conversation. A says "I'm not Canadian", B then replies "_I_ am" (with emphasis on _I_ in order to point out the difference), C, a third person altogether, agreeing with B (not A) says "I am _too". In this situation, __B cannot say "I am too", meaningfully, in response to A.__

Comment: If you want to reply to A saying "I am Canadian" in order to say the same, you'd say "I am not Canadian either" or maybe "I am also not Canadian" or shorter and less formal "Me neither".

Comment: @Mitch you are right. C is agreeing with B. This website confused me.

Comment: @Fumblefingers ""You can't speak English!" - "I can too!" is valid" - very North American.

Comment: Children respond this way all the time. It's extremely common. But it's said with a degree of emphatic emotion that indicates a specific context. If the response were said calmly and without inflection it would make no sense. But whine and stamp your foot while saying it, and it makes perfect sense.

Comment: As for the comma and the **too**, if **too** is the last word in the sentence, you don't *need* a comma in front of it. But you can have one if you like.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey:  You raise a valid point, but it’s not *really* relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

No, **too** is only used when you are in agreement.

EDIT:
Someone brought up the American slang of *"Can too."* in reply to *"You can't X."* I'm English so I can't speak for how common it is there, but it's definitely ungrammatical at the very least.